# Laravel: select pivot column with scope

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I Wanna Show Details, It's Simple!
I use ScopeFilter function in my model (Estate):

```
public function scopeFilter($query, $zone = null,  $type = null) {
    $query->whereHas('types',function ($query) use ($type) {
        $query->whereTitle($type);
    })->whereHas('zone',function ($query) use ($zone) {
            $query->whereSlug($zone);
    });
    return $query;
}`enter code here`
```

were is my controller (estate controller):

```
$estates = Estate::filter($zone,$type)->latest()->paginate(12);
```

and here is my relation :

```
public function types()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Type::class)->withPivot('slug');
}
```

I have an additional column in my many to many table like:

```
estate_id| type_id |   slug  |
------------------------------
    a    |    b    |   a_b   |
    c    |    d    |   c_d   |
```

I do everything fine
**just need show details with where on 'slug' column in my many to many table.**

Comment: `whereHas('types',function ($query) use ($type) {
                $query->where('estate_type.slug',$type);
            })` Find It

Answer (score 0):

```
whereHas('types',function ($query) use ($type) { $query->where('estate_type.slug',$type); })
```

**Find It**